# Rails: How can I show/hide long text

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a table which has a column of type text_area and user can input long text to this field. I would like to show only the first 100 characters and hide the rest, and when user click "read more" the text expand. I have some code like this:

```
<td class="class-a"><%= truncate(project.description, length: 100) %><a onclick="showInFullView()"><em>read more</em></a></td>
```

And the function is inside the same script

```
<script>
function showInFullView() {
  ...
}
</script>
```

May I know how to write this 'showInFullView' function? I tried to render this row again but it will generate a new row underneath.

Or anyone has a better idea to make this feature work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Lots of links to help you out. Please follow the simple jquery tips for it. 
1) http://shakenandstirredweb.com/240/jquery-moreless-text
2) http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/
etc.

Comment: @RajeshOmanakuttan make it an answer please.